# É possível criar uma agenda no Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

Eu preciso criar uma agenda de contatos "privada" (sem ser a da própria API do celular).

Por exemplo:
    Tenho o BOTÃO (A) e BOTÃO (B); 
    Tenho a AGENDA (A) e AGENDA (B);

- Quando o usuário clicar no BOTÃO (A), ele vai ser mandado pra Activity da AGENDA (A);
- Quando o usuário clicar no botão (B), ele vai ser mandado pra Activity da AGENDA (B);

No caso, cada contato de cada agenda seria adicionado pelo próprio usuário. Mas então, isso seria possível de fazer? Se sim, qual seria o "nome correto" dessa funcionalidade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, isso é possível, vejo 2 maneiras de se fazer.

O básico são 2 botões como você mesmo disse, e cada botão vai carregar uma lista diferente, o código para mudar de activity seria basicamente o seguinte:

```
public void BotaoA_Click(View v)
{
    Intent lista1 = new Intent(this, Lista1.class);
    startActivity(lista1);
}
```

Esse código fara com que quando for clicado o seu botão "A", ele vá para a activity da lista 1 de contatos.

## 1º maneira

Por estar aprendendo, creio que de inicio, para fazer essa lista, o melhor seria criar um arquivo .txt, na raiz do seu celular contendo as informações básicas que quer, exemplo: Nome, telefone, Celular e assim por diante. Ao clicar em adicionar contato ele adiciona nesse arquivo com uma tabulação básica utilizando as classes `FileWriter` e `BufferedWriter`.
E desse arquivo .txt você faz um `ListView` lendo o arquivo que você criou com as classes `FileReader` e `BufferedReader` para mostrar os seus contatos, e ao clicar no item, ele abre o contato com mais detalhes.

## Exemplo da implementação do FileWriter e BufferedWriter

```
public void writeLog(String writeIt)
{ 
    try { 
        FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
        bufferedWriter.append(writeIt);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error(Log)", e.toString());
    } 
}
```

## Exemplo da implementação do FileReader e BufferedReader

```
public String[] readFile()
{ 
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] vStrings = null;
    if (file.exists()) {
        FileReader fileReader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String lineString;
        int count = 0;
        try { 
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while ((lineString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lista.add(lineString);
            } 
            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
            vStrings = new String[lista.size()];
            vStrings = lista.toArray(vStrings);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error(readFile())", e.toString());
        } 
    } 
    return vStrings;
}
```

Onde a variável `file` é um objeto do tipo `File` que tem o `path` do arquivo a ser escrito e lido.

## 2º maneira

Caso se sinta já confortável para fazer uma programação um pouco mais elaborada, vale a pena você utilizar o `SQLite` e ter uma organização dos seus registros bem melhor, podendo assim fazer as mesmas coisas que a `1º maneira` faz, de um jeito mais elegante e melhor.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Mas então, como estou começando agora, vou tentar fazer o primeiro método e depois tentar utilizar o 2º método com o SQLite. Não tenho muito conhecimentos sobre B.D, mas vou ir tentando e estudando esse método. Valeu, abraços!